# Access denied; you need the SUPER privilege for this operation - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have my user `root` with all privileges on, I checked over and over and still show the same error, but wheren I try to change the value of the variable `max_user_connections` FROM `phpmyadmin` it display this error, in the plesk interface (I'm running a Windows server) where the list of user appear all the privileges of my user is enabled so I do not why this error.

But I ran this queries in `phpmyadmin`

`SHOW GRANTS;`

[image]

`SELECT USER();`

[image]

`SELECT CURRENT_USER();`

I get `root@%`

**(Sorry but Stackoverflow says that I can't post images because of my reputation and no more than two links)**

There is a difference between `root@localhost` and `root@%`?

And why in the first image the first line says `GRANT USAGE ON...`?

How I can give the `SUPER` privileges the user needs? thanks.

Comment: 1) yes, there is a difference 2)  you can list the databases in the mysql server 3) using the `grant` statement, which is well documented in the manual

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that can't do any changes because I need SUPER privileges besides the root user has all the permissions listed in the options

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with php or phpmyadmin, pls stop adding those tags back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't found a solution and nobody knew how to help me beyond to send me a manual with the definition of what `SUPER` means in `MySQL` so exploring all the files in my dedicated server and I found this path

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Databases\MySQL\data\`

I opened the `my.ini` file, I located the variable `max_user_connections` and I changed its value directly as I wanted, it solved my problem.